# Find next string after specific substring with RegExp

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I parse the PDF file from which I want to extract the name and surname from the table. I managed to get the text to this form. Now I would like to receive information from this.

```
Name1 • • • • • Surname1 Name2 • • • • • Surname2
```

I was thinking about putting a separator after the surname to make it look something like this

```
Name1 • • • • • Surname1 SEPARATOR Name2 • • • • • Surname2 SEPARATOR
```

I have absolutely no idea how to find the surname using regexp. The only thing that comes to my mind is to find the string '• • • • •' and then put a sperator after the next word (surname)

I'm not looking for a ready-made solution, but hints on how to do it. I will be grateful

Comment: You can try something as simple as [`(• • • • • \w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/U4kA14/1), but you'll have troubles with comples surnames, like "Bores de Silva". And I don't believe this is solvable with any kind of regex without initial proper format markup.

Comment: what if we assume that the surname will consist of ONLY one word?

Comment: In the case you've mentioned you need not additional separator as space after Surname will become natural separator.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that the surname is one word:

```
const inputString = "Tom • • • • • Hanks Morgan • • • • • Freeman Robert • • • • • Redford";
const regex = /(\w+)\s+•\s+•\s+•\s+•\s+•\s+(\w+)/g;
const matches = [];
let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
  const name = match[1];
  const surname = match[2];
  matches.push({ name, surname });
}
```

and you will get the result as:

```
matches
0:{name: 'Tom', surname: 'Hanks'}
1:{name: 'Morgan', surname: 'Freeman'}
2:{name: 'Robert', surname: 'Redford'}
```